# How do you properly store structures in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

As the title suggests, I am attempting to store a structure in C but want to find the most efficient way of doing so.  The answer certainly depends on the data being stored right?

I know of Linked lists and doubly linked lists, but I'm working with the Periodic Table which comes out to 118 elements with 29 unique fields for each element and I don't know if linked lists are even necessary.  Currently, I've tested out storing a few elements and 4 characteristics into a structure array.  There are ints, floats, and strings.

```
element[0] - atomicNumber: 1    element: Hydrogen       symbol: H       atomicMass: 1.0070
element[1] - atomicNumber: 2    element: Helium         symbol: He      atomicMass: 4.0020
element[2] - atomicNumber: 3    element: Lithium        symbol: Li      atomicMass: 6.9410
element[3] - atomicNumber: 4    element: Beryllium      symbol: Be      atomicMass: 9.0120
```

So, does anyone have any insight that might help guide me?

Comment: What problems you're trying to solve matter far more than the type of data you're dealing with.  That being said, this is still very likely an opinion question.

Comment: "most efficient" for what? Memory usage? Complexity? Insertion? Deletion? Lookup? Computing often involves tradeoffs so need to specify the exact requirements when making design decisions.

Comment: What are you going to do with the data? You're wondering if linked lists are even necessary, but so far you're in a better position to judge that than us. On the other hand, linked lists are rarely the answer anyway.

Comment: Linked lists can be useful if you'll be adding and removing items from the collection. But if it's a fixed-size collection, an array is usually appropriate.

Comment: You could even consider using a small database such as [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html).

Comment: If you're going to read/write this data from disk, then something simple like CSV would also seem to be viable (and easily reused beyond this application).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input.  My intent is to use the data to run calculations, equations, and functions against elements in the periodic table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends as much on the data being stored as it does on the way you want to use it.
A general pointer: if you know exactly how many elements there will be, a fixed-size array is usually a good idea.

```c
struct Element {
    int atomicNr;
    char symbol;
    // etc
};

Element elements[] = {
    {
       .atomicNr = 1,
       .symbol = 'H', 
    }, 
    // etc
};
```

You might even be able to get rid of atomicNr and just use the array index for that.

Comment: Thank you Wutz.  That is what I am currently doing.  If you couldn't tell I'm a bit of a novice/beginner and didn't know what questions to even ask or how to think about creating something useful.